# Any good Python reference book for Blender 2.8?

Tags: python, scripting

I am looking for a good reference book on Blender 2.8 or any recent blenders. I am coming with Python back-ground and want to work in blender mostly using Python as it gives excellent control over various aspects of this amazing program.

Comment: I recommend that you use the official docs, everything else will be out-dated and therefore not very helpful. https://docs.blender.org/api/current/index.html

Comment: @rjg I think this comment would make a great answer. Mind moving it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend that you use the [official docs](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/), everything else will be out-dated and therefore not very helpful.